# Django filter- Conditional Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Say I have 2 models:

```
class Product(models.Model):                                                
  name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)                                             
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
  scale = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)  

class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)  
  scale = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have the following filters for the queryset

```
products = Products.filter.objects(scale__isnull = False, scale__in = ['L1','L2'])
products_2= Products.filter.objects(scale__isnull = True, company__scale__in = ['L1','L2'])
```

is it possible to combine these filters into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and bitwise operators to combine conditions, so you can write this as:

```
from django.db.models import Q

products = Product.objects.filter(
    Q(scale__isnull=False, scale__in=['L1','L2']) |
    Q(scale=None, company__scale__in=['L1','L2'])
)
```

This yields a query that looks like:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN company ON product.company_id = company.id
WHERE (product.scale IN (L1, L2) AND product.scale IS NOT NULL)
   OR (company.scale IN (L1, L2) AND product.scale IS NULL)
```